Null value in excel
I have a question about  value*.
I am importing data into an Excel sheet using SQL (DB2) but I have a problem. I get many rows with  value and I want to remove them . I tried using If (A3="");"";A3) but it doesn't work! i don´t want to use filter because I want to save the excel as MALL so all null values disappear automat when sheet have a new value  .
Do you have any idea how to remove or hide null value  (NOT Blank ) .
it seems like this picture !
!
Thank you very much


Is it showing <null> like this? if so then why not use the Find and Replace feature in Excel

Yes it is  . the probelm is  that i want to save Excel as Mall  every time i oppen it , clear excel  Value  automatisk .

You can use Power Query (Get & Transform on the Data ribbon) to query data from a database. Clean the data up in the Power Query editor before loading it into the worksheet. The good thing about Power Query is that when the database data changes and needs to be refreshed, all the clean up steps will be repeated automatically and you only have to do the work one time when setting up the query.
In the PQ editor, you can replace the <null>with empty cells and make other changes as required.
